# Azure Function Timer Trigger Setting in Pipeline Variable

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have a C# timer-triggered is not triggering when deployed to Azure.  The timer trigger has a schedule setting using the variable `%Schedule%` with the actual schedule value CRON expression in the `local.settings.json` file when developing locally.

[image]

In the DevOps release pipeline, there is environment variable called "Schedule" that contains a CRON expression as the value.

When the function is deployed to Azure, I'm seeing the timer trigger value defined as `%Schedule%` instead of the CRON expression that is in the environment variables.  Is this correct or should the actual CRON expression (not `%Schedule%`) be visible in the Azure portal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you may check in your Azure Function app settings, if there is already a variable `Schedule` with your expected cron expression. Here is my sample function with a timer function for your reference.

[image]

According to this document on [Local settings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-settings-file),

> The `local.settings.json` file stores app settings and settings used by local development tools. Settings in the local.settings.json file are used **only** when you're running your project **locally**. When you publish your project to Azure, be sure to also **add any required settings** to the app settings for the function app.

In your scenario, the `value` in `local.settings.json` file may not affect the Azure Function timer trigger. It should be determined by the  `Schedule` variable in the app settings for your remote function app. Therefore, if there is no such `Schedule` variable in the app settings of the function app to which your code is deployed, the timer function will not be triggered.

To synchronize settings in the `local.settings.json` file with the [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings) in the function app to which your project is deployed,

> When you develop your functions locally, any local settings required by your app must also be present in app settings of the function app to which your code is deployed. You may also need to download current settings from the function app to your local project. While you can [manually configure app settings in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings), the following tools also let you synchronize app settings with local settings in your project:
>
> - [Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code#application-settings-in-azure)
> - [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings)
> - [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings)

From the perspective of Azure DevOps to leverage release pipeline to deploy Azure Function app and update app settings, please refer to the screenshot below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough response which answered my question.  My function setup appears to be correct per your screenshots, but the function still doesn't appear to be running on the schedule.  I'll create a different post if I find I can't determine why.